# OpenCV 2.4 putText() and Scalar understanding

Tags: c++, opencv, text, scalar

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.11 in C++. I want to display a text with the `putText()` function on my picture.
For example:

```
putText(imageOutput,"x:",Point(pos[0],pos[1]),1,1,Scalar(255,0,0),2);
```

What does the `Scalar` input do? Is there an alternative input instead of `Scalar`?

Comment: it's the text color, b,g,r. (and not a function, but a constructor of the Scalar class)

Comment: @berak Thank you! Is there an other way to define the color?

Comment: why do you want another way ?

Comment: I want to set a gray scale value

Comment: Scalar(13); // (same thing in gray)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
putText(imageOutput,"x:",Point(pos[0],pos[1]),1,1,Scalar(255,0,0),2);
```

Your question:

> What does the Scalar function do?

You are creating a Scalar object, you can see the documentation here

If you want to create a BGR (full colour) image then you can initialise the Scalar with `Scalar(B,G,R)`. However if you only want a greyscale image all you need to do is initialise it with your greyscale value:

```
Scalar(greyScaleValue);
```

so your code would be:

```
putText(imageOutput,"x:",Point(pos[0],pos[1]),1,1,Scalar(30),2);
```

for a greyscale value of 30.